# ¿Cuándo usar "conseguir" o "lograr"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Me parece que el sentido es de "to manage to do something", pero ¿hay alguna diferencia? ¿Cuál se usa con más frecuencia? ¿Uno es más formal que el otro?

Answer (score 7):

Los significados literales son diferentes. [«Conseguir»](http://rae.es/conseguir) es [«to obtain»](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obtain), [«logar»](http://rae.es/lograr) es [«to achieve»](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/achieve). Tu pregunta, si me permites que la repita con mayor claridad es: ¿Que verbo del castelleno es equivalente a «to manage to do something»?

Pues comparando «conseguir» y «lograr», la respuesta es ninguno. Si, si miras en el diccionario de la RAE, estas dos palabras tienen significados sinónimos. Pero, primero, el diccionario de la RAE no debe ser tomado como guía absoluta. Y segundo, los verbos «to achieve» y «to obtain» no son realmente equivalentes y tampoco significan la frase sobre la que preguntas. *«To manage to do something»* significa *«arreglarselas para hacer algo (bien)»* y en inglés *«to do something to the best of one's ability»*.

Estos verbos tienen significados diferentes en el uso. La pista está en el verbo [«obtener»](http://rae.es/obtener). Ambos verbos «conseguir» y «lograr» se pueden reducir a matices semánticos de este último, pero «conseguir» semánticamente se refiere a posesión, mientras que «lograr» se usa para referirse al alcance de metas, materiales o inmateriales a través de un esfuerzo personal. De hecho en ocasiones se combina ambos verbos para indicar el alcance de una meta material. Unos ejemplos:

- *«Carlos consigió un auto nuevo»*. Carlos *obtuvo* un objeto material.
- *«Carlos ha logrado graduarse de la universidad»*. Carlos *obtuvo* una meta inmaterial, fué un esfuerzo grande; tal vez se demoró diez años.
- *«Carlos logró conseguir el préstamo para comprar su casa nueva»*. Carlos hizo un esfuerzo material e inmaterial (todas las diligencias y
  requisitos impuestos por el banco) para obtener un objeto material
  (la casa).

En el primer ejemplo, no puedes reemplazar «conseguir» por «lograr». No suena bien, la frase *«Carlos logró una casa»* no es idiomática y demuestra poco conocimiento del uso de idioma, algo que uno escucharía entre gentes de los bajos fondos. En el segundo si es intercambiable, el esfuerzo implica una inversión material: trabajo, tiempo, lapso de vida. Estas dos ideas se conjugan en el tercer ejemplo.

Comment: Me gusta este punto de vista. Además de que pareces tener razón, lo cierto es que logras evadir la mecánica de escoger una u otra o de utilizar el diccionario de sinónimos para definir. Mientras más miro los diccionarios de sinónimos más pienso que son para ayudarnos a hacer nuestros propios cuestionamientos.

Comment: aunque me ha gustado tu respuesta ( de hecho te he dado puntos), en realidad no respondes la pregunta que es en realidad lo que aparece en el título ¿Cuándo usar “conseguir” o “lograr”?

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero Pues creo que si lo hice. :-) En castellano, conseguir y lograr son casi sinónimos de acuerdo al diccionario pero en cuanto al uso son diferentes, lo que se vé al obervar su uso de equivalencia con palabras inglesas que *no* son sinónimas. Y de otro lado, la frase idiomática inglesa no se traduce, ni significa, ninguna de esas palabras en castellano.

Comment: Esta respuesta es buena, pero mejoraría mucho con algún ejemplo donde se viera cúando podrían ser usados como sinónimos y cuándo no se podrían sustituir de ninguna manera.

Answer (score 1):

Ambos pueden utilizarse como equivalentes a *"to achieve"* en la mayoría de construcciones, y puedes utilizarlos como sinónimos para evitar la redundancia.

> lograr nuestras metas ayuda también a conseguir la felicidad

Sin embargo, al menos en América, conseguir también se utiliza como sinónimo de *obtener algo* en un sentido de *"to get something"*:

> vamos al campo a conseguir algunas fresas

Comment: Ya que hablas algo de la agrciultura si las fresas no salen buenas no se dice que no se consiguieron se dice que no se lograron. Estas dos palabras no son sinónimos en muchos mas casos. Cierto que en algunos casos si son sinónimos pero no se puede decir que sean puramente sinónimos.

Comment: @Ernesto, mi ejemplo con las fresas no es en relación a el _logro_ de la cosecha. Pude decir igual "Vamos al supermercado a conseguir algunos alimentos enlatados", lo cuál es perfectamente normal en donde vivo, y el ejemplo busca precisamente demostrar que no siempre son sinónimos, pues no puedes decir "vamos al supermercado a _lograr_ algunos alimentos enlatados".

Answer (score 0):

En realidad puedes utilizar ambos, son sinónimos, y los dos significan lo mismo.

*...to manage to do something...*

*...lograr algo...*

*...conseguir algo...*

Yo jamás he visto ninguna diferencia entre ellas dos, he comprobado, por si acaso si no eran sinónimas, pero por lo general se usan para no hacerse repetitivo en un texto, por ejemplo cuando tienes que usar el mismo verbo dos veces muy junto, es buena práctica usar *conseguir* primero y *lograr* después, o a la inversa.

Un saludo

**EDIT:**

La respuesta se ha redactado teniendo en cuenta el contexto en el que nos sitúa la pregunta sobre *...to manage to do something...*

Comment: En muchos casos no son sinónimos y no se pueden sustituir uno por otro. Por ejemplo no se logró la cosecha.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero en el contexto de lo que dice la persona que tiene la duda son totalmente sinónimos, de hecho, el diccionario de la RAE incluye lograr en la definición de conseguir y viceversa. Explícame esto por favor, porque no comprendo la oración que pones de ejemplo, ni "no se logró la cosecha" como "no se consiguió la cosecha", supongo que quieres demostrar que no puedo cambiar consiguió por logró, pero me suenan igual de mal ambas, ¿podrías ponerme la oración en contexto? Muchísimas gracias :)

Comment: Si no te queda claro, con el ejemplo de la cosecha que por cierto lo que dices no se debe decir asi pero bueno. La cosecha se logra o no se logra. en el caso de una cosecha no puede decirse que se consigue o no se consigue.  Consígueme un martillo. ¿Cómo lo dices con el verbo lograr?

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero no es más probable que se diga, de manera más correcta con la definición de la RAE "no se obtuvo la cosecha"? Que a su vez es sinónimo de lograr y conseguir, con lo cual, se demuestra que se pueden intercambiar, porque tu estás usando lograr cuando yo uso obtener, y podríamos usar conseguir, o encontrar gente que usase conseguir. Me tiene confuso este caso, porque no veo tu respuesta, y me interesa saber que es lo que piensas.

Comment: Lograme un martillo o obtieneme o un martillo??????? Se dice consígueme. Y las cosechas se logran es totalmente correcto, y mas preciso que obtener.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero con el martillo sucede justamente lo mismo que con el resto, estamos hablando del contexto, no usaremos lógrame un martillo, pero, y si es igualmente correcto, donde dice que no lo sea, porque no se oiga no significa que no sea correcto, como siempre, deberíamos tener la opinión de un profesional para esto, pero lo que dice el diccionario de sinónimos es que lograr y conseguir es lo mismo, y la definición de una contiene la otra. Me parece que intentas desvirtuar la respuesta de una manera un poco sucia, ya que no aportas nada.

Comment: @Amedio creo que lo que Ernesto intenta decir es que no son sinónimos en todos los contexto. De manera general si nos referimos a objetos /cosas materiales se "consiguen" u "obtienen" más no se "logran".

Comment: @Laura están tan en guerra conmigo que una cosa tan obvia no la razona. Nada tiene que ver el uso con formalidad o no formalidad. conseguir se usa para cosas materiales y palpables. aunque en sentido figurado se use como sinónimo de lograr. Pero no son sinónimos ni puramente ni a medias.

Comment: @Amedio como ejemplo "Conseguí/obtuve (pero no logré)el martillo pidiéndoselo al vecino" a lo mejor es una de esas palabras que el matiz lo hacemos los hablantes por elección pero que, diccionario en mano, sí son sinónimos. Por otro lado en la acepción de"lograr" refiriéndose al crecimiento de un ser vivo llegado a buen término (malograr es su antónimo) no  puede ser sustituidopor "obtener" o "conseguir"

Comment: @Laura igualmente, puede que sea más un tema que no estamos acostumbrados a decir una u otra cosa, en el caso de la cosecha, en España, o al menos a mi, se me antoja más decir obtener y usar lograr me suena de locos. Que puede tener que ver con el contexto, pero creo que tiene que ver con lo que estés acostumbrado. Como ejemplo tienes el "asín" y "así" ambos son correctos, pero la gente se echa las manos a la cabeza cuando oye o lee "asín".

Comment: Obtener una cosecha es cosa diferente de lograrse.

Comment: @Laura también es posible decir "Logré el martillo pidiéndoselo al vecino" al fin y al cabo conseguir es "Alcanzar, obtener, lograr lo que se pretende o desea"

Comment: @Amedio estas en la tercera fase de la terquedad. Estaba intentando conseguir un martillo en un cuarto oscuro. No se puede sustituir por lograr.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero Ni tanto ni tan calvo. Son sinónimos pero, como la mayoría de sinónimos, no es todas sus acepciones.

Comment: Los lograr es para logros y metas. Conseguir es para cosas materiales. En algunos casos pueden ser usados como sinónimos. Pero ni en todos los casos ni incluso en la mayoría de los casos

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero pues explicame que es lograr una cosecha y sus diferencias, pon algo constructivo, porque sigo sin entenderlo, no es estar en guerra contigo, yo apoyo a todo el mundo que pasa por aquí, pero discutir algo sin una explicación plausible suena a que el que está en guerra con alguien eres tu, con el resto. A veces ya se sabe, y siento salirme de contexto, piensa el ladrón...

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero lograr un martillo en un cuarto oscuro es toda una meta compañero, a mi me suena correcto.

Comment: No no son sinónimos. En algunos contextos pueden tener puntos de posible sustitución pero aún en esos casos es preferible escoger entre uno y otro. Claro si hablamos en sentido figurado todo vale. Por ejemplo para el caso en específico si quiere obtener algo, habría que valorar si desea algo tangible o intangible. si es tangible de preferencia debe usarse conseguir, si es intangible de preferencia debe usarse lograr.

Comment: Lograrse una cosecha es que llege a término que se obtengan frutos que no hayan por ejemplo plagas que impidan la recolección de los frutos. Aunque los frutos sean materiales aqui no se habla de los frutos propiamente sino de la cosecha si ha llegado a término la meta en si.

Comment: Lograrse de preferencia para cosas intangibles, conseguirse de preferencia para cosas materiales o tangibles.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero entonces no puedo decir que hemos conseguido una buena cosecha, o no hemos conseguido la cosecha... la verdad es que a mi me parece tan correcto lograr como conseguir en este caso...

Comment: Conseguir una buena cosecha no es lo mismo que lograr una cosecha.

Comment: Pero te das cuenta @ErnestoMarrero que simplemente estás diciéndome que el uso de lograr es preferente para algunas cosas, pero no excluyes el posible uso de su sinónimo.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero según tu explicación, para mi significan lo mismo, con lo cual volvemos al tema de, lo que cada uno use en su casa.

Comment: @Amedio mira en google donde aparece lograrse cosechas e intentalo sustituir por conseguir verás que no se puede. Incluso puede que comprendas lo que es lograr. Lograr se refiere a metas a cosas intangibles. Conseguir es para cosas materiales. Cierto que en algunos casos pueden sustituirse uno por otro pero aún en esos casos sigue existiendo escoger una óptima entre las dos valorando si es algo material o inmaterial.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero, esta prespuesta se desvirtuo totalmente y creo que el problema aqui fue que no entendiste que Amedio y jachguate dijeron que "conseguir" y "lograr" eran sinonimos unica y exclusivamente bajo el contexto del significado en español de "to manage to do something".

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero no mires en Google, que no es un buen traductor o un buen solucionador de dudas, te lo digo por experiencia. Yo creo que estamos hablando de un tema de uso del término a nivel regional, que hay veces que las cosas no nos suenan bien, pero hay otra persona en la otra punta del globo a la que le suena a música celestial.

Comment: @Dante es que aún en ese caso no son sinónimos en español. Si quiere conseguir algo material lo óptimo es utilizar conseguir, si busca alguna meta lo correcto es lograr. http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/lograse

Comment: Lograr es conseguir algo que se intenta conseguir se refiere a cosas materiales http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/lograse Asi que en el presente caso el algo hay que valorar si es un algo material o un algo inmaterial.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero, con ese link me acabas de dar la razon, uno de los significados, segun la pagina que mencionaste, es: "**Conseguir** lo que se intenta". Entonces, nuevamente, bajo el contexto de "to manage to do something" si son sinonimos.

Comment: @Amedio ahora es que he mirado alguna página y las definiciones. Sólo uso el sentido común. No he traducido. Pero se something es algo ese algo hay que traducirlo si es material o inmaterial para escoger si es apropiado conseguir o lograr. De cualquier modo ya si he visto mucha información donde se nota muy evidentemente que no son sinónimos. Y que no pueden sustituirse muy a la ligera sin caer en errores graves.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta aclarando que ha sido creada en base al contexto en el que nos sitúa la pregunta.

Comment: Conseguir para cosas materiales, lograr para metas intangibles.

Comment: No se que sentido tiene editar algo, para que parezca otra pregunta. Es como empezar a jugar un partido de fútbol y a la mitad cambiar las reglas del juego.

Answer (score 0):

El uso de uno u otro no tiene nada que ver con la formalidad, ni puede demarcarse uno como más frecuente que el otro. Es preferible utilizar "conseguir" para cosas materiales. Ej. *Quiero conseguir un martillo*.

Es preferible utilizar "lograr" para cosas no materiales relacionadas con el buen desempeño de algo, casi siempre una meta. Ej.: *No se logró la cosecha por culpa de la sequía.*

En muchas ocasiones una puede ser sustituida por otra pero aún en esos casos si delimitamos si es algo material (conseguir) o inmaterial (lograr) serían los términos óptimos.

En el presente caso, aún cuando "something" se refiera a algo inespecífico, se deduce que sea algo material. Y es evidente que lo apropiado es "consígueme algo" a la opción de "lógrame algo".

Comment: Bueno tengo un menos uno parece que alguien dice lograme algo.